# Overriding rendered CSS class in Vuetify framework

Tags: css, vuetify.js

On just one of the components inside my app I need to change this framework rendered class `application--wrap`

The issue is, is that I have other components that don't need that class overwritten and the standard class is fine.

I obviously can do this:

```
.application--wrap {
  min-height: 1vh !important;
}
```

As well as `scope` it to the one component, the issue though is that it needs to be overwritten in the main `app.vue` file but only applied to the one component.

I've tried overwriting the class this way, but it hasn't worked:

```
.myClass.application--wrap {
  min-height: 1vh !important;
}
```

At a loss right now, any help out here?

Comment: What is the dev tools' inspector saying why your rule doesn't get applied?

Comment: How do you import vuetify css? Order of importing css file is important.
`require('/path/to/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css')
require('your_custom.css')`